# Who was Angel Eyes trying to shoot first?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly

During the finale of *The Good, The Bad And The Ugly* it was clear that Blondie was always going to shoot Angel Eyes, given his prior knowledge that Tuco's gun was unloaded.  It was also clear that Tuco was going to shoot Angel Eyes because of his prior affiliation with Blondie.

I've watched the film numerous times, but can't make out who Angel Eyes was going to shoot.

It would make sense for him to shoot Tuco given that Blondie might not have written anything on the rock.  On the other hand, it would make sense to shoot Blondie because he is the best shot (but did Angel Eyes know that?).

Comment: I like this question but I wonder if it can really be answered objectively using evidence from the film...

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, [there is a page](https://archive.nerdist.com/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-final-shootout-analyzed/) about this, saying

> No joke, no hyperbole, Sergio Leone‘s 1966 film The Good, the Bad, and the Ugly is my favorite movie of all time.

Hum, ok, same for me! But that's not the point, here it is

> Tuco is probably going to shoot Angel Eyes, but he’s a wildcard, so maybe he’ll shoot Blondie to get the money all for himself. Blondie knows that Tuco’s gun is empty—which Tuco, and we at home, don’t find out until the end of the sequence—and also knows that *Angel Eyes* is very likely going to *shoot at him*.

We know that Angel Eyes is likely to shoot both Blondie and Tuco ; who is he going to shoot first? We don't have a definitive answer. It is a matter of opinion anyway.
(And I don't recall Leone talking about that point in the DVD special features).

So, in my opinion, Angel Eyes would shoot first Blondie, because

- He certainly thinks higher of Blondie than of Tuco (remember also the scene at the camp, AE vs Tuco, then AE vs Blondie), and he probably wants to get rid of him first, Tuco would be a bit less of a threat.
- Even though Tuco has his gun (unloaded but he doesn't know), the scene seems to emphasize a duel between Blondie and Angel Eyes (Tuco being passive until a gun plays).
- The images from the scene tend to show the direction of AE's gun towards Blondie (he is right-handed, so it's not a definitive proof).

There is also an amazing video on that page, that deserves to be watched. It shows how clever the movie is. (It's too bad Leone is not with us anymore to see it :-(

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Angel eyes because Tuco was aiming at him. Then the best choice would have been shooting Blondie after Blondie killed Angel Eyes if he got the first shot.